# Negative energy density

Tags: general-relativity, energy, cosmology, dark-energy, cosmological-constant

There are some universe models where $\Lambda < 0$. In this case, the energy density of the dark-energy becomes negative. At this point, does it make sense to talk about "negative dark energy density"? Or is it possible to think of this energy as curvature on space-time? Such that, $\Lambda < 0$ will imply a negative curvature and $\Lambda > 0$ positive one.

For instance if we have a only matter with $\Omega_m = 0.3$ the universe will have negative curvature with $\Omega_{\kappa} = 0.7$.

When we add positive dark energy such that $\Omega_{\Lambda} = 0.7$ we would have $\Omega_{\kappa} = 0$.

If we add negative dark energy such that $\Omega_{\Lambda} = -0.7$, we would have $\Omega_{\kappa} = 1.4$

So adding positive energy density increases the curvature.

In other words is there a something call "negative" energy density ? or
Does all negative energy densities are thought in terms of the curvature effects on space-time?

Answer (score 1):

Negative energy density may exist theoretical and the closest believed real phenomenon is the [Casmir effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casimir_effect). If it exists, it does cause repulsion of ordinary matter, though how it happens is a little more indirect.

When there are two plates, that are very closely placed in an environment that has 0 energy density, the possible wavelengths that can exist in between the plates is limited. This leads to fewer wavelengths of electromagnetic waves, than is found in the surroundings. This causes an energy density lower than 0, which is basically negative. This is [Casmir effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casimir_effect) in simple words. The Wikipedia link given can give better insights.

The Wikipedia link [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_mass) talks about something quite similar.

Comment: The Casimir effect shows less energy density between the plates compared to outside. This doesn't necessarily mean negative energy density between the plates.

Comment: The plates exist in an environment of zero energy density. Hence lower than outside is zero. I suggest you read the Wikipedia page for more clarification, that is linked above and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casimir_effect).

Comment: Wikipediia writes: The Casimir effect shows that quantum field theory allows the energy density in certain regions of space to be negative relative to the ordinary vacuum energy- Note please "relative to". Also please note "zero point energy" does not mean zero vacuum energy density. If you have a reference which says otherwise then please show it.

Comment: @timm If my understanding of the following excerpt from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_mass) is correct, it answers your argument.

_Currently, the closest known real representative of such exotic matter is a region of negative pressure density produced by the Casimir effect._

Comment: Thanks for this link which I still interpret as a relative statement regarding the pressure. As you may say see from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_energy) the value of the vacuum energy density is simply not known. So I stick to the "relative" comparison to be on the safe side.

Comment: I have edited it accordingly. I misinterpreted the articles I quoted. Thank you, @timm. I have learnt something.

Comment: My pleasure, @Manish. :)